# How to change URL format using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the format of my URL. Suppose my page is

```
example.com/add.php?mod=new
```

I want to change it to

```
example.com/add/new
```

I found the following code but it only remove file extension from the url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another rule to handle query parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to support /add/new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?mod=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: That is because of relative paths. To fix you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: I am trying it on new project but again I am getting Internal Server Error. Can you please help me :)

Comment: I paste error log here [link](http://pastebin.com/bgUiXc5E)
localhost/bkg/department.php?did=1 this is the actual link of my project.

Comment: Can you update the question with your full .htaccess because `localhost/bkg/department.php?did=1` won't be affected with both the rules in my answer.

Comment: I am only using your htaccess

Comment: Then I suspect something other than these rules as both of these rules won't impact the URL you're using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129829/discussion-between-abdullah-and-anubhava).

Comment: its working now. But there are two problem nows. Its not acceptiing only numbers like 1, 2 etc. And the second thing is support for page I have parameter did and for other page I have parameter cid then what i have to do for this

Comment: `\w` allows for numbers also. Also I suggest creating a new question so that you can explain your problems clearly with examples.